# How to resolve repeat function in kotlin it is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, repeat, fast-android-networking

here is my code How to use repeat function in kotlin :

```
    var it = 0

    val uploadImage=AndroidNetworking.upload(Constant.BASE_URL + "app.php?api=editprofile")
    repeat(imagesFiles.size){
        uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image", imageFileOne)
        uploadImage.addMultipartFile("image${it+1}", imagesFiles[it])

    }
    it++
```

Comment: repeat is not working even it is a default function in kotlin

Comment: Have you got any error log?

Comment: getting error in this repeat so cant log

Comment: I guess you have some error in your ide or kotlin environment

Comment: may be like this